# Cloudfront cache display mobile view for desktop users

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudfront

I am using cloudfront caching for several weeks now (7 days caching).
Since then, I have several pages for which the mobile version is displayed to desktop users, as if the cache was storing a mobile version for every users.

Here is the terraform configuration of cloudfront:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_cache_policy" "proxy_hubspot_cache_policy" {
  name        = "custom-caching-policy"
  comment     = "Our caching policy for the Cloudfront proxy"
  default_ttl = 604800 # seven day of cache
  max_ttl     = 604800
  min_ttl     = 604800
  parameters_in_cache_key_and_forwarded_to_origin {
    enable_accept_encoding_brotli = true
    enable_accept_encoding_gzip   = true
    cookies_config {
      cookie_behavior = "none"
    }
    headers_config {
      header_behavior = "none"
    }
    query_strings_config {
      query_string_behavior = "all"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_request_policy" "proxy_hubspot_request_policy" {
  name = "custom-request-policy-proxy"
  cookies_config {
    cookie_behavior = "all"
  }
  headers_config {
    header_behavior = "allViewer"
  }
  query_strings_config {
    query_string_behavior = "all"
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "proxy_cdn" {
  enabled = true

  price_class = "PriceClass_100"

  origin {
    origin_id   = local.workspace["cdn_proxy_origin_id"]
    domain_name = local.workspace["cdn_domain_name"]

    custom_header {
      name  = "X-HubSpot-Trust-Forwarded-For"
      value = "true"
    }

    custom_header {
      name  = "X-HS-Public-Host"
      value = local.workspace["destination_url"]
    }

    custom_origin_config {
      origin_protocol_policy = "https-only"
      http_port              = "80"
      https_port             = "443"
      origin_ssl_protocols   = ["TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"]
    }
  }

  default_cache_behavior {
    viewer_protocol_policy   = "redirect-to-https"
    allowed_methods          = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE"]
    cached_methods           = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id         = local.workspace["cdn_proxy_origin_id"]
    cache_policy_id          = aws_cloudfront_cache_policy.proxy_hubspot_cache_policy.id
    origin_request_policy_id = aws_cloudfront_origin_request_policy.proxy_hubspot_request_policy.id
    compress                 = true
  }

  logging_config {
    include_cookies = true
    bucket          = data.terraform_remote_state.shared_infra.outputs.cloudfront_logs_s3_bucket_url
    prefix          = "proxy_${local.workspace["env_type"]}"
  }


  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }

  viewer_certificate {
    acm_certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.proxy_certificate.arn
    ssl_support_method  = "sni-only"
  }

  aliases = [local.workspace["destination_url"]]

  depends_on = [
    aws_acm_certificate_validation.proxy_certificate_validation
  ]

}

resource "aws_cloudfront_monitoring_subscription" "monitor_www_proxy" {
  distribution_id = aws_cloudfront_distribution.proxy_cdn.id

  monitoring_subscription {
    realtime_metrics_subscription_config {
      realtime_metrics_subscription_status = "Enabled"
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea what can be wrong in the configuration?

Thanks a lot

Comment: "as if the cache was storing a mobile version for every users." As you have it configured now, the cache is storing whatever the last response was from the server, for every user. You haven't done anything to tell CloudFront to store cache differently for mobile versus desktop users.

Comment: But how can we update the configuration to store cache differently for mobile versus desktop users ? Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: How are you rendering different mobile versus desktop views from your server now? What is the thing you are using to determine if it is a mobile or desktop user? Is it the `user-agent` header?

Comment: yes most likely the user-agent header !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to get CloudFront to cache mobile pages separately from desktop pages is to configure the `CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer` and `CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer` [headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-cloudfront-headers.html) as part of [the cache key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-device). Note all the headers that are available there, if you also want separate cache for table viewers, or iOS and Android caches, etc.

The Terraform config would look like:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_cache_policy" "proxy_hubspot_cache_policy" {
  name        = "custom-caching-policy"
  comment     = "Our caching policy for the Cloudfront proxy"
  default_ttl = 604800 # seven day of cache
  max_ttl     = 604800
  min_ttl     = 604800
  parameters_in_cache_key_and_forwarded_to_origin {
    enable_accept_encoding_brotli = true
    enable_accept_encoding_gzip   = true
    cookies_config {
      cookie_behavior = "none"
    }
    headers_config {
      header_behavior = "whitelist"
      headers {
        items = ["CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer", "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer"]
      }
    }
    query_strings_config {
      query_string_behavior = "all"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that these headers will also be passed to your backend origin after you implement this configuration, so you could change the logic of your application to render mobile vs desktop based on the value of those headers instead of inspecting the `user-agent` header.